# Wordpress shopping cart add dynamic products to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I am searching for a cart solution that will help me meet my needs so I don't have to re-invent the wheel. Here is the situation...I have a very dynamic and complex product setup -- something that won't fit in a standard product/variation cart.

So what I'd like to do is manage the products and simply send a description and price to a cart system that will do the rest (take payment through paypal, record the order, etc)

Does anyone know of a wordpress cart that is extensible enough that can process an order without having an actual product tied to it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Another option would be to have a single product (which in my case, it's a single item, just with thousands of variations) as long as I could override the price and description that gets sent along with the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own solution. I had looked at wp-e-commerce, but wasn't too thrilled at how it did thing or the documentation on extending it.

Answer (score 0):

There is wordpress plugin for that. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/